# ignoring the space delimiter in java

Tags: java, string, delimiter, space

I am looking for a way to input a sentance as a single string, how would I do this?
I could also just use a file as an input (.txt), but I don't know how to approach it.

I basically want to ignore the 'space' delimiter, and need help finding out how

what I have so far:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int rand = randomGenerator.nextInt(10)+1;
    System.out.print("Enter code to be encoded. End the text with a semicolon(;): ");
    String in = input.next();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Confirmation: Encode the following text? y to accept, n to decline");
    System.out.println(in);
```

Edit:
added src
I'm working on an encoder for me and some friends, and want to do sentances at a time instead of words at a time. Yes, they will end with a period.

Comment: What do you have so far? maybe nextLine is your solution but I'd prefer to see something to start with.

Comment: [Scanner ... nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())

Comment: What constraints do you have on your input?  Are periods ONLY at the end of sentences?  Is there just 1 sentence per line of input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the delimiter to ";", if you want to use ";" as delimiter:

```
input.useDelimiter (";")
```

Comment: thanks. I take it should have a semicolon at the end of the line?